# Extract a representative subset of an xml file for parser testing

Tags: xml, rdf, owl

I have a rather long xml/rdf/owl file that I need to parse into a set of dictionaries that I am using. In order to be able to unit-test my parser during the future, I would need to extract a representative subset of the xml file, without breaking the xml/rdf/owl stack syntax.

Is there a better way to do it than manually copying elements from a real parsed file?

Answer (score 3):

## Solution 1 with the Protégé editor

You can use the [Protégé](http://protege.stanford.edu/)  `Refactor` -> `Copy/move/delete axioms...` menu entry to select a subset and export it to a new file.
[image]
[image]

## Solution 2 with the Pellet reasoner

You can use the extract functionality of the [Pellet reasoner](https://github.com/complexible/pellet). This allows you to extract a subset based on the type of assertions.

```
PelletExtractInferences: Extract a set of inferences from an ontology

Usage: pellet extract [options] <file URI>...

Argument description:

--help, -h 
     Print this message 

--verbose, -v 
     Print full stack trace for errors. 

--config, -C (configuration file) 
     Use the selected configuration file 

--statements, -s (Space separated list surrounded by quotes) 
     Statements to extract. The option accepts all axioms of the OWL functional 
     syntax plus some additional ones. Valid arguments are: [DefaultStatements, 
     AllClass, AllIndividual, AllProperty, AllStatements, 
     AllStatementsIncludingJena, ClassAssertion, ComplementOf, 
     DataPropertyAssertion, DifferentIndividuals, DirectClassAssertion, 
     DirectSubClassOf, DirectSubPropertyOf, DisjointClasses, 
     DisjointProperties, EquivalentClasses, EquivalentProperties, 
     InverseProperties, ObjectPropertyAssertion, PropertyAssertion, 
     SameIndividual, SubClassOf, SubPropertyOf]. Example: "DirectSubClassOf 
     DirectSubPropertyOf" (Default: DefaultStatements) 

--loader, -l (Jena | OWLAPI | OWLAPIv3 | KRSS) 
     Use Jena, OWLAPI, OWLAPIv3 or KRSS to load the ontology (Default: 
     OWLAPIv3) 

--ignore-imports 
     Ignore imported ontologies 

--input-format (RDF/XML | Turtle | N-Triples) 
     Format of the input file (valid only for the Jena loader). Default 
     behaviour is to guess the input format based on the file extension.
```

Comment: Sounds great, where can I find the docs and an example of usage for it?

Comment: Protégé usage is rather intuitive. Pellet usage needs some command line manipulation. Run `pellet help` to obtain help. Ask if you encouter problems.

Comment: Ok, to start with, how do I install pellet?

Comment: I've used protege before, but I wasn't aware they added subset extraction. That's actually a pretty nice thing to know, thank you.

Comment: For Protege, I tried exporting a subset of entries, but it was transforming the tags that were making it incompatible with previous parse. The biggest modification is the modification of xml url namespace upon export from a different project and the convention of tags.

Comment: I think, it's better to ask a new question detailing, with precise examples, this problem.